# Domain and TS migration

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, licensing

The migration steps outlined by Microsoft in the ts migration seem to deal with moving TS to a different server on the same domain and call for adding the licensing service to another system, move the licenses and then put TS on whatever server you want.  However with migrating the domain as well I don't have any place to move the TS server to.

So my thought was to simply re-activate my licenses on the new server using the same method as a new TS setup.  My question is essentially will this work the way I think it will or will the MS activation clearing house deny the new server?  Is there a procedure to follow that "deactivates" the licenses on a server so that the clearing house knows there are some free?

(FWIW I can look up the license information through the eopen website and have access to the original license doc.)

Answer (score 0):

Worked just as expected.  The license and agreement numbers were the only things I required, both readily available from the eopen website.